# Fitting a rectangle into screen with XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am drawing a rectangle with primitives in XNA. The width is:

```
width = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width
```

and the height is

```
height = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

I am trying to fit this rectangle in the screen (using different screens and devices) but I am not sure where to put the camera on the Z-axis. Sometimes the camera is too close and sometimes to far.

This is what I am using to get the camera distance:

```
//Height of piramid
float alpha = 0;
float beta = 0;
float gamma = 0;

alpha = (float)Math.Sqrt((width / 2 * width/2) + (height / 2 * height / 2));
beta = height / ((float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(67.5f)) * 2);
gamma = (float)Math.Sqrt(beta*beta - alpha*alpha);

position = new Vector3(0, 0, gamma);
```

Any idea where to put the camera on the Z-axis?

Comment: What scenes is it too close for and what scenes it too far away? Your code looks like it should be producing consistent results. Also what projection are you using - perspective or parallel/orthographic?

Comment: I'm using perspective with fov:PiOver4. Just want the primitive rectangle that I draw to fit the screen when I load the game (since its size is equal to the screen)

Comment: Can you post screen shots of the "too close" and "too far" cases?

Comment: Lets say the rectangle is red. On a windows machine the whole screen becomes red and I have to zoom out a lot so that I can see tha background. On the windows phone its the other way around. The rectangle seems smaller so I see the background and I have to zoom in to fill the screen.

Comment: What is the purpose? A full screen effect?

Comment: Just what to do a fullscreen panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to doing this is to **draw the rectangle directly in raster space**. This is the space that the GPU works in when actually rendering stuff.

Normally your model starts in its own model space, you apply a world transform to get it into world space. You then apply a view transform to move the points in the world around the camera (to get the effect of the camera moving around the world). Then you apply a projection matrix to get all those points into the space that the GPU uses for drawing.

It just so happens that this space is always - no matter the screen size - from **(-1,-1)** in the bottom left corner of the viewport, to **(1,1)** in the top right (and from 0 to 1 on the Z axis for depth).

So the trick is to set all your matrices (world, view, project) to `Matrix.Identity`, and then draw a rectangle from (-1,-1,0) to (1,1,0). You probably also want to set `DepthStencilState.None` so that it doesn't affect the depth buffer.

---

An alternative method is to just use `SpriteBatch` and draw to a rectangle that is the same size as the `Viewport`.

Comment: I am going to try it out. A question though, why should the SpriteBatch have a different behavior than the primitive?

Comment: It doesn't. `SpriteBatch` has an implicit orthographic projection matrix that covers the screen (properly pixel aligned and everything). It transforms client space to raster space. After being transformed, the quad that `SpriteBatch` creates should land at coordinates as if you put it their directly. The reason I mention it is that it can a bit easier to simply throw together (particularly if you are already doing 2D work).

Comment: the pyramid was a wrong approach. I just used the Tan and it worked. Also tested your solution and it works.